# Tomcat crashed with unexpected error

Tags: linux, java, crash, tomcat, jvm

Tomcat server crashed with the unexpected error detected by the java virtual machine. And `hs_err_pid.log` file was also generated during the crash.

hs_err_pid log file captured 'V  [libjvm.so+0x256a2f]' as a problematic frame and the current thread was "CompilerThread0".

I am trying to find a Root cause of this crash. And what can be done to prevent such crash...

### Version

```
Tomcat : 5.5.23  
JDK : build 1.5.0_18-b02  
OS : RHEL 5.11
```

### Error in the Catalina.out file

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002b542236ba2f, pid=11943, tid=47641176217920
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (1.5.0_18-b02 mixed mode)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x256a2f]
#
[thread 47641272080704 also had an error]
# An error report file with more information is saved as [thread 47641272080704 also had an error]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

### hs_err_pid.log

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002b542236ba2f, pid=11943, tid=47641176217920
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (1.5.0_18-b02 mixed mode)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x256a2f]
#
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
Current thread (0x000000005ccb9040):  JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11998]
siginfo:si_signo=11, si_errno=0, si_code=1, si_addr=0x0000000000000000
Registers:
RAX=0x00002b545db4bd60, RBX=0x00002b545de78d10, RCX=0x00002b545db4ba58, RDX=0x00000000000008c1
RSP=0x00002b5453626d80, RBP=0x00002b5453626e00, RSI=0x000000000000000b, RDI=0x0000000000000400
R8 =0x00002b5454ff2100, R9 =0x0000000000000007, R10=0x00002b545cd486c0, R11=0x00002b5422a80020
R12=0x000000000000004a, R13=0x000000000000004a, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x00002b545de83900
RIP=0x00002b542236ba2f, EFL=0x0000000000010206, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00002b5453626d80)
0x00002b5453626d80:   00002b5422981060 00002b5453626dd0
0x00002b5453626d90:   00002b545436d710 0000000000000000
0x00002b5453626da0:   00002b545de83900 00002b545cd48690
0x00002b5453626db0:   0000001c00000004 00002b5454ff2100
0x00002b5453626dc0:   00002b54536272b0 0000006022416196
0x00002b5453626dd0:   00002b545db4bd60 00002b545de83900
0x00002b5453626de0:   00002b545de83900 00002b545db4bd60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a JVM bug and was probably fixed in [1.5.0_19](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/releasenotes-142123.html#150_19) (see "hotspot compiler" bug fixes) or a newer version. But maybe not...

You should look into an upgrade of your system including Tomcat and Java. JDK 1.5 has reached its end of life [a decade ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history).

If that's not easily possible, try an upgrade to the last version [JDK 5.0u22](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html) or [JRE 5.0u22](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html#agreementDivjre-1.5.0_22-oth-JPR).

A useful matrix of Tomcat versions and its supported Java versions can be found here: [Apache Tomcat Versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).